# How to set default cms language to english?

Tags: django, django-cms

How to set default cms language to english? Currently if someone from Russia visit my site have

> mysite.com/ru/

I need always

> mysite.com/en/

as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the LocaleMiddleware to not inspect the browser's the Accept-Language, but default to English if no preference is set.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/ Django sets default language based on `Accept-Language` header.

If you want always redirect users from / to /en/ than set rewrite in your web-server config.

nginx example:

```
location / {
    ...
    rewrite ^/$ /en/ permanent;
    ...
}
```